# Personalized storybook-like program that parents and teachers can change the pictures but not the text

Tags: open-source, educational, printing, books

I want to create a storybook and give it to other users who then should be able to alter the images of the storybook but not the text.

This storybook will be retasked to teach autistic and intellectually disabled children to read and comprehend what they read and allow parents or teachers to change the pictures to personalize the reader for the child's needs.

I thought JAVA would be a good choice but any program will work as long as it can be used on the Internet and any browser or app. An online / web based tool would be good as well.

The parents must be able to print the storybook for their personal use at home at no cost.

Comment: Are you open to online applications?

Comment: Hi Nicolas,Yes, absolutely. In fact, online would be perfect.

Comment: I upvoted, and will keep it in mind if I come across anything that fits your requirements.

Comment: You limit this to open-source tools. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Taking into  consideration the last requirement you mentioned, that of being able to print the books yourselves, I looked around and found [StoryJumper](http://www.storyjumper.com). Although they are, naturally, trying to advertise their own publishing services, I found burried in an example what suggests that you may be able to download your own copies.

Per [this example](http://www.storyjumper.com/main/classroom):

Step 8: Print Students' Books

Sara has the following options to print her classroom's books (highest to lowest quality):

- Professional-grade, Hardcover Book
- Paperback Book
- **High-Resolution, Digital Download** -> this you should be able to print...unless tgere's a catch.
- Low-Resolution Printing with a watermark

You may want to explore this possibility. For more questions, they mention contacts at the bottom-left of the same page.

Answer (score 1):

[Bookemon](http://www.bookemon.com/video.php)'s presentation video makes it sound like a good choice for you, especially since you said that online platforms are acceptable. I highly doubt you will find a solution that allows you only to edit the pictures and not the text.

Feats:

- free to create your books, free to share online
- ability to import quite a few file formats, to add them to your book (pictures, docs)
- templates already included

I hope this tool will fit your needs and allow you to brighten the days of those children, it is such a noble cause. Good luck!

Comment: You are welcome. Let me know how you find this for your needs, to know whether I should be on the lookout for something else.

Comment: Just visited Bookemon. Good program but it's only free to make the books, it costs $10.00 to print them out. I don't want to do that to the parents of these kids. I envision them being able to change the pictures and print the book out at home for free. Thank you for the link though. I really appreciate it. Mike

Comment: I see. If this is a requirement as well, could you please edit the initial question to include this detail? I thought the books were going to be used online exclusively. I'll take another look when I get a chance.

Comment: I found a JQuery booklet code http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/ which I think will work with the addition of upload, drag and drop code added. Then I have to figure out how to make it all work on mobile platforms and different devices. Please visit the site where the code is, Thanks

Comment: Looks good! Once you have it integrated on a website, it should, theoretically, work on whatever modern (actual) browser that particular device has. This is not quite my area of expertise, but I think you might have found something very interesting. You may still want to check what I suggested below, having a turn-key solution, in case it satisfies all the requirements, will certainly be easier.

Comment: Will do. Thank you so much for the guidance and assistance.